# ios safariのwindowsでのデバッグ方法

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, debugging

ios版safariのjavascriptデバッグをwindowsで行いたく色々と調べておりますが、うまくいきません。

以下のサイトを参考にios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32を試してみましたが、
https://qiita.com/tyam001/items/dc9f44add8e31dcbfa7a
Unable to connect to chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com:80となってしまいます。

ios版safariのデバッグ(コンソール画面の表示)をwindowsでやっていられる方がいましたら、ご教示願います。

Localサーバーを建てWiFi接続でweinreでデバッグできるようになりました。
ただ、javascriptのデバッグをするには、あまり使い勝手がよくないと感じました。
・ステップ実行ができない。
・console.logが表示されない。logが表示されないのは使い方のせいでしょうか。一部のログのみ出力される感じです。ご存知の方よろしくお願いいたします。

また、リモートデバッグでjavascriptのステップ実行ができるものは無いでしょうか。
ご存知の方、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: もし、そのツールに拘りがあるのならスルーして欲しいのですが、weinreを使うのはダメでしょうか？(クロスプラットフォームでは試験しないのでしょうか？)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。androidはwebinspctで行っています。weinreでも同様のことができるのですね。試してみます。ありがとうございました。